# How to make the popup window overlay the article

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-like

I'm having trouble figure out about this Facebook Like button when I press like it suppose to popup overlay the article but mine it just goes behind the text and the user can't press or do anything at all

[image]

---

Unlike the other website which I found to give an example from Theverge

their popup overlay the article and there won't be any problem to continue to send to facebook wall

[image]

This is the CSS for the share button that I have right now

```
/* Share */
.share-post {
    clear: both;
    margin: 10px -20px -20px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    background: #F7F7F7;
    border-top: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    height: 20px;
}

.mini-share-post {
    clear: both;
    margin: 10px -20px -20px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 25px;
    height: 20px;
}

.recent-box .mini-share-post {
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.share-post li, .mini-share-post li {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
}

.share-post span.share-text {
    background: #FF8500;
    margin: -10px 10px -10px -10px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 9px;
    font-family: BebasNeueRegular, arial, Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 14pt;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `z-index` of the `div` (or something else, depends on what you use) that your posts are wrapped in and set a higher one for the Facebook widget.

Usually setting `z-index: 1001;` works for me in such situations, but such a high value is considered as rather dirty fix.

## EDIT

Okay, I know what is wrong now (I assume it's the site from your profile).
There is a `span` inside a div with class `fb-like fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget`. Change the `span` width to about 500px.

So you don't have to change the `z-index`, but next time, **please** provide some code. Not everthing can be guessed from images.

Comment: I'm really sorry about that... I'm trying to digg from whatever information that you provided me right now and will get back to you as soon as possible

Comment: @Ali - if the `div` is generated by the FB plugin and you can't see it in your code, please check if you can set it its preferences. If that won't help - you can try to add CSS properties inside your own file (and propably you will have to add `!important`, too)

Comment: Sorry @Pablo Lemurr, it was my mistake the code that I have now provided on the top and it is actually from the homepage of the site not the single_post.php